# Best way to control firefox via webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to control Firefox browser via webdriver. Note, I'm not trying to control page elements (i.e. find element, click, get text, etc); rather I need access to Firefox's profiler and force gc (i.e. I need firefox's Chrome Authority and sdk). For context, I'm creating a micro benchmark framework, not running a normal webdriver test.

Obviously raw webdriver won't work, so what I've been trying to do is

1) Create a firefox extension/add-on that does what I need: i.e.

```
var customActions = function() {
  console.log('calling customActions.')
  // I need to access chrome authority:
  var {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");
  Cc["@mozilla.org/tools/profiler;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProfiler);
  Cu.forceGC();
  var file = require('sdk/io/file');
  // And do some writes:
  var textWriter = file.open('a/local/path.txt', 'w');
  textWriter.write('sample data');
  textWriter.close();
  console.log('called customActions.')
};
```

2) Expose my `customActions` function to a page:

```
var mod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
mod.PageMod({
  include: ['*'],
  contentScriptFile: data.url("myscript.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on('callCustomActions', function() {
      customActions();
    });
  }
});
```

and in `myscript.js`:

```
exportFunction(function() {
  self.port.emit('callCustomActions');
}, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "callCustomActions"});
```

3) Load the xpi during my webdriver test, and call out to global function `callCustomActions`

---

So two questions about this process.

1) This entire process is very roundabout. Is there a better practice for talking to a firefox extension via webdriver?

2) My current solution isn't working well. If I run my extension via `cfx run` directly (without webdriver) it works as expected. However, neither the sdk nor chrome authority do anything when running via webdriver. 
By the way, I know my function is being called because the log line "calling customActions." and "called customActions." both do print.

Maybe there are some firefox preferences that I need to set but haven't?

Answer (score 3):

It may be that you do not need the add-on at all. Mozilla uses [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette) for test automation of Firefox OS amongst other things:

> Marionette is an automation driver for Mozilla's Gecko engine. It can
>   remotely control either the UI or the internal JavaScript of a Gecko
>   platform, such as Firefox or Firefox OS. It can control both the
>   chrome (i.e. menus and functions) or the content (the webpage loaded
>   inside the browsing context), giving a high level of control and
>   ability to replicate user actions. In addition to performing actions
>   on the browser, Marionette can also read the properties and attributes
>   of the DOM.
>
> If this sounds similar to Selenium/WebDriver then you're correct!
>   Marionette shares much of the same ethos and API as
>   Selenium/WebDriver, with additional commands to interact with Gecko's
>   chrome interface. Its goal is to replicate what Selenium does for web
>   content: to enable the tester to have the ability to send commands to
>   remotely control a user agent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, is there anyway to making Marionette work with Webdriver (didn't seem like it when I read, but just checking). The reason why I need this to work with webdriver and not another webdriver-like server/client is because I need the solution to work with not only firefox, but also for Chrome/mobile/other platforms, and it is not practical to start different servers for different browsers.